# Tracking Direct2D rendering

Tags: directx, win32gui, direct2d

By default, Direct2D picture is displayed on the screen after the function EndDraw.

For debugging purposes, I need the picture to be displayed on the screen after drawing of any draw primitive.

Is this possible in Direct2D? 
In GDI for these purposes I used GdiSetBatchLimit(1)

Comment: Although it won't display on screen, you may be able to isolate an error by periodically calling [`ID2D1RenderTarget::Flush`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd316801%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You'll need to BeginDraw/EndDraw around every primitive. If you have layers or clips you'll need to set and remove them around every primitive too.

[Drawing operations can only be issued between a BeginDraw and EndDraw call.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371768%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

You can render GDI content on a D2D target ([Direct2D and GDI Interoperability Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd370971%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

Or else you can try with a loop that will encapsulate one primitive (then two, then three until the end of your drawing code) inside Begin/End's. Just like the pseudo code below:

```
for (i=0; i<number of primitives; i++)
{
    Begindraw;
    Drawprimitive0;
    if (i == 0)
    {
        EndDraw();
        continue;
    }

    Drawprimitive1;
    if (i == 1)
    {
        EndDraw();
        continue;
    }

    Drawprimitive2;
    if (i == 2)
    {
        EndDraw();
        continue;
    }

    etc.
}
```